# Multiple Ethernet Ports losing configuration and not getting up after boot

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, configuration

I have recently installed **Ubuntu Server 20.10** on **Desktop PC**, with 3 ethernet ports on that PC.

The problem is that:

1. Whenever the server is rebooted, the ethernet ports do not automatically go up while it is connected.
2. The Ethernet ports lose IP configuration that I have assigned to
   them.
3. I have installed tasksel GUI to have graphical interface but it is
   not showing me any network cards information when I go to
   Settings>Network.

Your guidance would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu server uses Netplan for network configuration. It would be useful if you can find your netplan config file (it's in `/etc/netplan` and has a `.yaml` extension - the filename  itself may vary) and post the contents of the configuration file. Also, have a look at [netplan.io](https://netplan.io/examples/) for config examples.

Comment: Also, maybe it's the same problem as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209689/netplan-configuration-not-persistent)?

Comment: Hi @ArturMeinild. Thank you for your reply. The file contains the following configuration. I have added the last two by myself:

#This is the network config written by 'subqiuity'
network:
ethernets:
eno1: 
addresses: 
- 192.168.1.143/24
gateway4: 192.168.1.1
nameservers:
addresses:
- 8.8.8.8
enp3s0f0:
addresses:
- 10.10.10.99/24
gateway4: 10.10.10.1
enp3s0f1:
addresses:
- 10.10.10.100/24
gateway4: 10.10.10.1
version: 2

Comment: Please post the contents in your original post, not in the comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. The file contains the following configuration. I have added the last two by myself:

```
#This is the network config written by 'subqiuity'
network: 
ethernets: 
    eno1: 
       addresses:
       - 192.168.1.143/24 
       gateway4: 192.168.1.1 
    nameservers: 
       addresses:
       - 8.8.8.8 
    enp3s0f0:
        addresses:
        - 10.10.10.99/24
        gateway4: 10.10.10.1
    enp3s0f1: 
        addresses:
        - 10.10.10.100/24 
        gateway4: 10.10.10.1
```

Comment: There are several errors in the yaml format in that file. The `ethernets:` section should be indented under `network:`. Also, I don't know if it's valid that the `nameservers:` section is "parallel" to the interfaces - normally the `nameservers:` are listed (and indented) under each interface.

Comment: Also, test you config with this command to see if the config is valid: `netplan -debug try`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your guidance on this!! I can't believe that it is finally working now.

Here's what I did:

- I tried the debug command `sudo netplan --debug apply`

I realized that I was not following the proper indention.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.143/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    enp3s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [10.10.10.99/24]
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
    enp3s0f1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [10.10.10.100/24]
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
  version: 2
```

Now, the IPs are static and not being lost after reboot.

Comment: Erhm, I don't understand your last sentence - is it working or not? You say the IPs are lost after reboot? Or are they NOT lost after reboot?

Comment: Haha, it is working now, Artur. Thank you! I missed the "Not" in excitement